# How to capture low-rankness of a symmetric matrix using its components (not eigenvalues)?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Suppose I have an optimization model (P1) which its decision variable is a symmetric matrix $W$ (but not necessarily negative/positive semidefinite). In my case, this model can be converted to a vector-based model using half vectorizing $W$; let this new equivalent model be (P2). I want to **only** work with (P2) and add a constraint to it or add a term to its objective function that promotes the low-rankness of the original matrix $W$ in (P1) when I go back. In other words, I want to revise the equivalent half-vectorized based problem (P2) in a way that once I go back to the original matrix $W$, it is low-rank.

Another way to think of this question is can I use the components of a symmetric matrix and promote low-rankness using them? I think one way to do this is using the trace of $W$ (which is solely based on components of $W$ so it can be used in (P2)) but I am not sure if minimizing the trace of a symmetric matrix (not necessarily negative/positive semidefinite) promotes its low-rankness! Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: In general, the trace tells you nothing at all about the rank of a symmetric matrix.  In fact, an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix can have rank $n$ when all the diagonal elements are $0$.  What you need to make it not have rank $n$ is that the determinant is $0$.

Comment: The determinant being zero only shows the rank is at most $n-1$! I guess you mean minimizing the trace and keeping the determinant zero, correct? Besides, I am looking for something easier based on components that captures low-rankness, any suggestions?

Comment: How about the Frobeinus norm?

Comment: algorithm to construct a nonsingular matrix $P$  such that $P^T W P = D$  is diagonal. At this point Sylvester's Law of Inertia  tells you the rank of $W$

Comment: Thank you but I cannot afford something complicated here, so I think I should ask my questions in this way: is there any norm that can capture the low rankness of a symmetric matrix? solely based on the components of this matrix!

Comment: The rank is $< k$ if and only if every $k \times k$ submatrix has determinant $0$.  But I don't see how a norm could be of much use.

Comment: What I mean is because we have $\|A\|_*\le \sqrt{r}\|A\|_F$ for a rank $r$ matrix $A$, so minimizing $\|A\|_F$ should promote low-rankness!?

Comment: You can add an arbitrarily small perturbation to a low-rank matrix, thus changing the norms by an arbitrarily small amount, but make it have full rank.

Comment: The same is true for even the nuclear norm, so I am not sure this is a valid argument here. Nuclear norm is well-established in this context I think.

Comment: @Sam The nuclear norm is to the L1 norm as the Frobenius norm is to the L2 norm. The Frobenius norm will fail to promote low rank for the same reason that the L2 norm fails to promote sparsity. Concretely, one argument is that the Frobenius norm produces a larger penalty for making a non-zero singular value larger than it does for making a zero singular value non-zero, whereas these penalties are the same for the nuclear norm.

Comment: @Sam It is worth noting that Will Jagy's suggestion is less expensive than eigenvalue computation

Comment: Is this a theoretical or a practical problem? Do we have to worry about numerical stability and round-off errors in floating point arithmetic, or do you perform the calculations with some sort of computer algebra system (CAS)? This has a huge impact on how to approach this problem.

Comment: I am designing a support vector machine which includes a matrix that needs to be estimated! I believe this matrix should be low-rank and I want to solve the corresponding problem but not using the SDP as it becomes expensive.  The best idea is to approximate low-rankness using a norm or solely based on the columns I think. So, eventually, these programs will be given to Python to be solved!